# Why is there no way to 'break on next statement' in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, ide, visual-studio-2017

I have been given a project that is the biggest pile of spaghetti I have ever seen, with 0 unit tests or any obvious naming conventions.

I find it hard to believe there is still no way while running in Debug to have Visual Studio automatically break on the next executing line of solution code.

In this case, I know the code is hitting a specific 5000 line of code file - but there isn't even an easy way to just write a breakpoint to every single line!

Is there any logical reason why in 2017 (or even 2010) this functionality doesn't exist?

Or perhaps it does and I haven't found out how!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365680/is-there-any-way-to-break-on-the-next-line-of-code-executed-in-visual-studio

Comment: seen it, the break-all 'trick' doesn't work at all. I 'break all' -> 'step into' then click a UI element and nothing happens. 

VS has the ability to only break on lines of code that are written as part of solution files, I don't understand why this doesn't exist - or the downvotes for that matter

Comment: isn't single step through the code what you are after? why you need 5k breakpoints?

Comment: I want to press a button on an ASPX page in WebForms, and have my debugger break at the first line of solution code. The break all trick doesn't work for me

Comment: @aspiring_expert, If you want to debug your app from the first line of the start up file, you could use the step Into, but if you mean that you want to debug your app in the line what you want during debugging, maybe the "Run To Click" or "Run to Cursor" would be helpful for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/07/run-to-click-debugging-in-visual-studio-2017/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/05/run-to-cursor/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any logical reason why in 2017 (or even 2010) this functionality doesn't exist?

Please Put a **break point in your code** -> **debug**, then **Right click on the text** editor in VS, you will see below:

[image]

Comment: not what i'm after at all - i said break on next statement, not set next statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Break all" button in the visual studio (Ctrl+Alt+Break is the default shortcut).

[image: Break all button in visual studio debug toolbar]

You might need to switch between the running threads in order to see highlighted instruction within your code.

[image: Thread selection in visual studio debug location toolbar]

Then you can just continue debugging, as usual.

If you do not see any of those two controls, go to View->Toolbars and check both "Debug" and "Debug Location".

Answer (score 0):

I normally just run until something happens, like a message box, or a longer running processing, and then Debug->Break all, and check stack trace.

This allows me to see the code I'm interested in.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please convert this post into a comment when you get the right to do it :) As you probably are aware, this would not qualify as answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)